# Spark SQL to get keys from a List of Nested JSONs

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset that contains a Column with the following nested data structure:

```
  Col1:
            {
                "info":
                [
                    {
                        "items":
                        [
                            {
                                "item1":
                                {
                                    "num": "0",
                                    "type": "a",
                                    "key": "new"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "item2":
                                {
                                    "num": "1",
                                    "type": "b",
                                    "key": "old"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "123",
                        "rank": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "items":
                        [
                            {
                                "item3":
                                {
                                    "num": "0",
                                    "type": "c",
                                    "key": "new"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "item4":
                                {
                                    "num": "1",
                                    "type": "d",
                                    "key": "old"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "345",
                        "rank": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "other_info": "3"
            }
```

I have tried the following however map_keys here also returns the keys from the inner nested json incorrectly.

```
"""
      SELECT 
        get_json_object(info, '$.id') as id,
        get_json_object(info, '$.rank') as rank,
        each_item, item_key, item_vals.num
      FROM
        TempTable
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(from_json(get_json_object(Col1, '$.info'), 'array<string>')) as info
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(from_json(get_json_object(info, '$.items'), 'array<string>')) as each_item
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(map_keys(from_json((get_json_object(each_item, '$.')), MAP(STRING, STRUCT<num: STRING, type: STRING, key: STRING>)))) as item_key
        LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(from_json((get_json_object(each_item, concat('$."', item_key, '"'))), STRUCT<num: STRING, type: STRING, key: STRING>)) as item_vals
"""
```

How do I get the keys from the outer json only, so that I get the combination of each unique item_key with the corresponding vals?

Comment: can you please share expected output ?